# How does medium affect the asymmetry of doppler effect in sound?

Tags: waves, acoustics, inertial-frames, doppler-effect

Firstly I would like to point out that I have seen several answers on the stack community similar to my question, however, I feel I haven't understood it quite yet

Doppler effect in light only depends on the relative motion of the light-emitting source and the receiving body, therefore there's symmetry (speed of source/receiver very less compare to the speed of light). But this isn't the case when dealing with sound. It turns out the asymmetry has something to do with  medium.

My question is: **In what way is the medium actually affecting the apparent frequencies and wavelengths?**

now based on my little google research the two phenomena aren't physically equivalent
(1.source stationary and observer moving, 2. source moving and observer stationary)

I honestly don't understand the role of the medium in doppler' effect ,could anyone provide a detailed explanation

**all answers are welcomed and please suggest edits if any **

Comment: This may be related. I am not sure if it addresses your issue very much though. [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364)

Comment: nahhh didnt help , im a high school student :\ . I have no idea about relativity

Comment: Special relativity is the key difference between light waves and sound waves. If you want to understand, I suggest looking for some simple introductions to it. This one might help. If not, there are plenty more. [What is relativity all about?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CB1QFUCga0I)

Comment: thanks !!! :)))