# Does the probability wave of a photon determine its color?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, visible-light

The wavelength or frequency of light determines its color. Photons seen as particles are said to have a frequency, determined by its energy, so I assume that 'is' the same color.

But being quantum particles, photons also have a probability wave, determining how likely it is to detect it in a certain state (like, a position). How do these waves relate to each other, if at all ?

Iow, would the double slit experiment have a different result when performed with 'red photons' instead of 'green photons', and if so, how would it differ ?

Sorry if I get things wrong, I'm just grappling with the nature of these things.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help or not - [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364).

Comment: Likewise this - [The more general uncertainty principle, regarding Fourier transforms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4)

Comment: It’s more like the colour influences the probability wave.

Answer (score 3):

Probability waves are are math calculation used to predict the outcome and do not determine anything physically. Yes the double slit experiment would have different results when performed with red photons instead of green photons. [image]
The higher the energy the shorter the seperation between fringes. In the attached photo you can see that the green fringes are closer together than the red fringes. In the single slit experiment interference comes sooner for the green light than the red light and again the green light has shorter distances between the spacing than the red light.