# Why do the subatomic particles like electron exhibits Dual-nature? And how does the particle knows when to change their state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

As we all know, Subatomic particles show dual-nature when observed but why? why does this happen? also I am genuinely confused as to how does the particle know when to change its nature, I mean i know that it changes when it gets *observed*(detected by a detector) But how does it know that it is being detected and now it has to change its nature

Comment: This may help - [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has troubled physicists for a century. What you're referring to is defined as the 'Measurement problem,' wherein a particle, initially described as a wave (i.e., a wavefunction), collapses when one attempts to measure its properties.

This doesn't imply that the particle is aware that we're trying to measure it or that it's intentionally tricking us by providing incorrect answers. Rather, within the wavefunctions, there are probabilities encoded for all possible states of the particle. Upon measurement, one of these probabilities manifests as an outcome.